# How to calculate FAR and FRR in pattern recognition?

Tags: biometrics

I am working on a vein pattern recognition project based on SURF algorithm and euclidean distance. I have completed my program to find the maximum and minimum distance between vein features and find a match exactly when there is an identical image. i.e max and min distance between two images is zero. In this case, how would I find my FAR and FRR. Will it be 0% or am I missing a big concept here?

Even if there is a slight variation it wouldn't match in which case, I guess I need to have a threshold value to compare to. I have calculate the max and min distance between all combination of images with the same hand, with different hands. In this case, how do I computer the FAR and FRR. This is my first biometrics project and it would be helpful if I am directed to any resource that would help me in this.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with security.  Maybe try https://scicomp.stackexchange.com  or https://cs.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: It was an evil thing to simply close this question, you had to migrate it to cs.stackexchange.com .